# Angular routing, remove old component first

Tags: angular, routes

I am using [**routerLink]="['my-route']"** . But the problem that angular routing renders first new component and then remove old one from the dom. it impacts on my new component, As I am doing some calculations with component position, so they are wrong.

I would like to change the order, first remove the old, then render new. Is it possible?

I know there is possibility to use resolver, it waits with rendering. but it seems like that's not something I need

Answer (score 0):

You can postpone rendering of a new component until the old one is removed.

In the component that you are navigating away from, listen for the route change by implementing OnDestroy

```js
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router'; constructor( router: Router ) { router.events.subscribe(e => { if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) { doSomethingBeforeTheComponentStartsRendering(); } }) } ngOnDestroy() { doSomethingBeforeTheComponentStartsRendering(); }
```

Now, there's another problem. You need to delay rendering of the new component.

One way to implement it is to create a custom router outlet, like this

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, Renderer2, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef, ComponentFactory, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core'; import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router'; import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'; interface Component { component: any; inputs?: object; outputs?: object; } @Component({ selector: 'app-custom-router-outlet', template: ` <div #target></div> `, }) export class CustomRouterOutletComponent implements OnDestroy { @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target; private routerSubscription: Subscription; constructor( private router: Router, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver ) { this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(e => { if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) { this.render(); } }) } private render() { setTimeout(() => { const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.component); const ref: ComponentRef<any> = this.target.createComponent(factory); Object.keys(ref.instance) .forEach(key => { if (this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.data.state[key]) { ref.instance[key] = this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.data.state[key]; } }); }, 0); } ngOnDestroy() { this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe(); } }
```

Now, you can use this custom router outlet instead of the default one.

`<custom-router-outlet></custom-router-outlet>`

The final step, is to provide the data to the new component.

In the component that you are navigating away from, you can use the router data property and just set the state data

`this.router.navigate(['/'], { state: { foo: 'bar' } });`

In the custom router outlet component, you can access the state data

```js
Object.keys(ref.instance) .forEach(key => { if (this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.data.state[key]) { ref.instance[key] = this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.data.state[key]; } });
```